# Making Authlogic 'not remember me'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, authlogic, remember-me

I want my user session to end when the user closes the browser. But authlogic seems to remember the session even when a new browser is opened. I have tried setting @user_session.remember_me = false but that doesn't help. I drilled down to the save_cookie method which is indeed saving the cookie with :expires => nil. Am I right in assuming that this will expire the cookie with the browser session?

The only peculiar thing about my authlogic configuration is that I set c.perishable_token_valid_for(0) so that the invitation code never expires. Not that I think it has anything to do with this ..

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate your problem. You might be putting it in the wrong method. Try this, put the @user_session.remember_me right in the create method:

```
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
  end

  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    @user_session.remember_me = false
    if @user_session.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created user session."
      redirect_to requests_url
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried with this HTML input attribute?:

```
autocomplete = "off"
```